# Example of Egoroff fails

Tags: measure-theory, baire-category

[image]

This picture comes from the book "Measure and Category" by John C.Oxtoby, page 37.

When the power of 2 is inserted into the linear function, the function isn't continuous anymore, unless the constant domain definition is changed, for example plug in n=3.
In [0,1/2] we will get 16x, in [1/2,1] we will get 2-16x, I can't figure what am I missing.

Comment: What happened to $r_i$ in your calculation ?

Answer (score 2):

You need to check your calculations again.

$\phi (2^{n}(x-r_i)$ is continuous because it is a composition of $\phi$ and the function $x \to 2^{n}(x-r_i)$The series defining $f_n$ is uniformly convergent since it is dominated by $\sum \frac 1  {2^{n}}$. So $f_n$ is continuous.